# What is the meaning of base["Description"] and Create(username)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can any one describe for me the role of `base[""]` and `Create()` in this code?

```
public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
{
    public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(string username)
    {
        return Create(username) as UserProfile;
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
    public string Description
    {
        get { return base["Description"] as string; }
        set { base["Description"] = value; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `base["Description"]` syntax is what is known as an [`Indexer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) in .NET. You can define indexers on your own classes with a property declaration using the `this` keyword like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    //indexer (could use int or anything else that your underlying collection supports)
    public string this[string index]
    {
        get
        {
             //retrieve from internal cache/collection/etc based on index
        }
        set
        { 
             //set internal cache/collection/etc based on index and value
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like

```
var myclass = new MyClass();
var value = myclass["index"];
myclass["another"] = "new value";
```

In your example, `ProfileBase` has defined an Indexer, and `UserProfile` is accessing it via the `base` keyword, since `ProfileBase` is the base class of `UserProfile`.

Comment: please describe `Create(username)`?

Comment: @mojtabasabet Describing method `Create` - this is a method with non-creative name, possibly creates instance of profile for given user name. May demonstrate  either usage of some design pattern or complete lack of understanding of constructors. Likely accepts single string as parameter, but may have more with default values. Does not look sexy or overly smart - just your average method. Usage will not make you stand out in a crowd.

Answer (score 0):

With [`base`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword you call/access a base class implementation of the property/method/member.

Comment: in this example my base class that is `ProfileBase` does not contain Description property/method or member. as i know to access base class property or method we must use `base.methodname()` not `base["method name"]`

Comment: @mojtabasabet, that depends. Post your base class `ProfileBase` definition.

Answer (score 0):

[`Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151825(v=vs.110).aspx) comes from 
[`ProfileBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase(v=vs.110).aspx)

ProfileBase in turn inherits from [`SettingsBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsbase(v=vs.110).aspx) which has an [`Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsbase.item(v=vs.110).aspx) property that is an indexed property which is where `base["Description"]` comes from.